# How do I store a count of a manytomanyfield in a model or filter and aggregate a manytomanyfield

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I have a model where I want to create a ranking for the count of a manytomanyfield. Only it expects an integer field instead of a manytomany field. I have a problem with the votes__lt.

Would the best course of action be creating a votes_count integerfield that counts the votes or is there a way to fix this code so it works?

```
class ContestEntry(TimeStampedModel):
   votes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='vote_entry')

   def ranking(self):
        aggregate = ContestEntry.objects.filter(votes__lt=Count(self.votes)).aggregate(ranking=Count('votes'))
        return aggregate['ranking'] + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.annotate` for this:

```
def ranking(self):
    return ContestEntry.objects.annotate(
        nvotes=Count('votes')
    ).filter(
        nvotes__gt=self.votes.all().count()
    ).count()
```

Here we thus first annotate the `ContestEntry`s with the number of votes `nvotes`, and then we count how many `ContestEntry`s there are with more `nvotes` than the number of votes of the `self` object.

Comment: Where do I annotate? I get the error Cannot resolve keyword 'nvotes' into field

Comment: @DedicatedDreamer: sorry made a typo, it is `.annotate(..)` instead of `.filter(..)`.

Comment: Thanks, this method however is very slow takes 1500 milliseconds and the leaderboard goes from 4 to 34 queries with very little votes and very little entrys. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: @DedicatedDreamer: if you want to make a leaderboard, just `.order_by('-nvotes')` *all* the `ContestEntry`s, and thus iterate over a `QuerySet` already ordered by the database.

Comment: @DedicatedDreamer: can a `Profile` make multiple submissions? If yes, then what is the ranking of that profile?

Comment: Sorry I mean detailview of entry

Comment: @DedicatedDreamer: for a single it is probably not possible to do it much faaster, since a rank is relative to other  items. The idea of using a `.order_by('..')` is that it will do the same amount of work, but this for an entire *collection*of objects.